# Mysql select in 1 table, update 2 table

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-update

There are three tables:

**shop_product_skus** - a table for the item 1 product ( 1 to many )

`shop_product_skus(id,product_id,sku,sort,name,image_id,price,primary_price,purchase_price,compare_price,count,available,dimension_id,file_name,file_size,file_description,virtual)`

**shop_product_stocks** - a table of how many products in different warehouses

`shop_product_stocks(sku_id, stock_id, product_id, count)`

**shop_product_ostatki** - this is a temporary table with the amount of product , price and sku from one warehouse , for example stock_id = 1 ( 1 is updated every 30 minutes)

`shop_product_ostatki (id, sku, count, price)`

**Foreign Key Relations**

```
shop_product_skus.product_id = shop_product_stocks.product_id
shop_product_skus.sku = shop_product_ostatki.sku
shop_product_skus.id = shop_product_stocks.sku_id
```

Now I need to update data from `shop_product_ostatki`

In table `shop_product_skus`

```
update shop_product_skus.price = shop_product_ostatki.price * 1.07,    
       shop_product_skus.purchase_price = shop_product_ostatki.price * 0.7 
where shop_product_skus.sku = shop_product_ostatki.sku
```

In table `shop_product_stocks`

```
update if there is no prompt to add 
      shop_product_stocks.count = shop_product_ostatki.count, 
      shop_product_stocks.price = shop_product_ostatki.price * 1.07 
where shop_product_skus.sku = shop_product_ostatki.sku 
  and shop_product_skus.id = shop_product_stocks.sku_id
```

Probably explained a little confusing , I do it all in one query.

For 4 days I struggle with this issue, search by stackoverflow enjoyed similar questions not found :(

ps sorry for my english

**UPDATE**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90f67

**UPDATE**
I'm try this, it's not worked

```
  INSERT INTO shop_product_stocks (sku_id ,stock_id ,product_id ,'count')
    (SELECT id.b ,product_id.b ,sku.b ,sort.b ,name.b ,image_id.b, price.b ,primary_price.b ,purchase_price.b ,available.b  FROM shop_product_skus b 
        LEFT JOIN shop_product_ostatki c ON c.sku = b.sku  
        LEFT JOIN shop_product_skus a ON a.sku = c.sku
     WHERE shop_product_stocks.stock_id = 1
    )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    'count' = 'count'.c
```

**UPDATE**
error in select

```
SELECT *  FROM shop_product_skus AS b 
    LEFT JOIN shop_product_ostatki_sander AS c ON c.sku = b.sku  
    LEFT JOIN shop_product_stocks AS a ON a.sku_id = b.id
 WHERE a.stock_id = 1
```

but all expr not worked

Comment: create a sqlfiddle for your tables and then post your required output.

Comment: sorry what is sqlfiddle?

Comment: i'm found, it's sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: yes its something where you simulate your problem and then every can analyse it.

Comment: i'm create sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90f67